# EF 7 Migrations. Web project, DBContext and Migrations in different assemblies

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have three projects in my solution.

`BaseApp.Data` - which holds my DBContext.

`BaseApp.Data.ProjectMigration` - which holds all migration files (depends on `BaseApp.Data`)

`BaseApp.Web` - web application with Startup class.

I added my first migration like this:

```
dnx ef migrations add Initial -p BaseApp.Data.ProjectMigration
```

After this command the Migrations folder appears with all corresponding files in `BaseApp.Data.ProjectMigration`. So everything is ok so far.

Than I try to apply migrations:

```
dnx ef database update
```

After this command the database is created, but no migrations applied. I also tried

```
dnx ef database update -p BaseApp.Data.ProjectMigration
```

with same result. Also next command returns "No migrations were found".

```
dnx ef migrations list -p BaseApp.Data.ProjectMigration
```

Also if I add migrations to `BaseApp.Data` then everything works fine. The next commands work as expected:

```
dnx ef migrations add Initial -p BaseApp.Data

dnx ef database update
```

So is it possible to hold migration files not in DBContext project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll also need to set your migrations assembly.

```
options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .MigrationsAssembly("BaseApp.Data.ProjectMigration");
```